# Comparison of string lengths in C using strlen

Tags: c, printf, unsigned, signed, strlen

I am quite confused with the behavior of `strlen`,the for loop below never ends (without adding the `break`) when try it, while the i < -2 should return False in the first step.

Is it related to my compiler? What did I misunderstand?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char a[] = "longstring";
    char b[] = "shortstr";

    printf("%d\n", strlen(b) - strlen(a)); // print -2

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(b) - strlen(a); i++)
    {
        printf("why print this, %d  %d\n", i, strlen(b) - strlen(a));
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
-2
why print this, 0 -2
```

Comment: the return value of `strlen` is `size_t` which is an *unsigned* integer type. So the subtraction leads to unsigned integer underflow

Comment: You are also invoking *undefined behavior* in the `printf` calls since you use the wrong format specifier `%d` instead of `%zu`

Comment: Why are you using so many `strlen`? `sizeof` will do and be more efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion specifier in this call of printf

```
printf("%d\n", strlen(b) - strlen(a)); // print -2
```

is incorrect. The function `strlen` returns a value of the unsigned integer type `size_t`. So this expression `strlen(b) - strlen(a)` also has the type `size_t`. So you need to write either

```
printf("%d\n", ( int ) strlen(b) - ( int )strlen(a) ); // print -2
```

or

```
printf("%zu\n", strlen(b) - strlen(a)); // print a big positive value.
```

In the condition of the for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(b) - strlen(a); i++)
```

the expression `strlen(b) - strken(a)` as it has been mentioned above has the unsigned integer type `size_t`. So its value can not be a negative and represents a big positive value.

Again instead you need to write

```
for (int i = 0; i < ( int )strlen(b) - ( int )strlen(a); i++)
```

Or you could write

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i + strlen( a ) < strlen(b); i++)
```

Comment: @EdHeal The compiler can optimize the for ;loop.

Comment: @EdHeal He used break to avoid an infinite for loop.

Comment: @EdHeal What? There is a for loop in the question.

Comment: @EdHeal All is evident except for you. This is not real his for loop. His actual loop is infinite. And he is trying to understand why his actual loop is infinite. So it inserted the call of printf in this loop and the break statement for testing to understand what is going under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

`strlen(b) - strlen(a);`  is a negative number

and `i` is 0 or +ve

Therefore the loop

```
 for (int i = 0; i < strlen(b) - strlen(a); i++)
```

Will never end as `i` (+ve)  will never be -ve